How to load properties in spring boot at runtime after the application started without restarting it
application.properties
spring.age=10
After starting the spring boot app, I'd like to make a change in properties.
application.properties
spring.age=20
The age=20 should be loaded without the need to restart the spring boot.
I tried with @ConditionOnProperty but even this has to be restarted to reflect if I am not wrong.

@Chaosfire no, it doesn't. The answer there is about using annotations for the properties, but when changing that, you would still have to restart

@Stultuske That's not the only approach explained in the answer.

What is your use case? What are you trying to do exactly?

Do any of the approaches mentioned here help?
There are mentions of

Using Spring Cloud's refresh capabilities
Building the ability in-house to refresh the context by using @Scheduler's

Both of the approaches do seem like over-kill but again depends on your scenario.
If what's needed is an ability for the application to be aware of application property changes and restart then you could use GitOps frameworks such as ArgoCD. These frameworks can auto refresh the application based on changes(commits) made in Git. It will take responsibility of re-installing the applications.
I couldn't find any such existing feature in springboot docos atleast

You have to restart when changing application.properties. This file served by Spring and in the sentence
@Value("${spring.age}")
String springAge;

this value was used when Spring bean was created.
Even if you change the property it will have no effect.
You should think of another way of using properties.
You can read application.properties every minute for example
and if property changed set the corresponding value manually.
